# Which form of "fill" goes here?

Tags: verb-forms, exam-questions

> Q) like humans, zoo animals must have a dentist ----- their teeth
>
> 1. fill
> 2. filled
> 3. filling
> 4. to be filled

could you please tell me , which is the correct word and why ?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please [edit] your question to explain why you think particular words might or might not work in that space. That way we'll know specifically what you're having trouble understanding and can answer your question better.

Comment: #2 and #4 are completely ungrammatical. Both #1 and #3 are credible, but offhand I can't say when the continuous form #3 might be preferred (though I'm pretty sure that in OP's *exact* context, the unmarked infinitive #1 would be much more common).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, is it an example of the subjunctive mood?

Comment: @user2738748: I'm no expert on terminology at this level, but I'm pretty sure *The dentist demanded [that] he **be** well-paid* is subjunctive, as would be *He asked [that] the dentist **fill** their teeth* . And OP's example here does look to be the same basic construction, so I'd guess the answer is probably *Yes*.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:"Like humans,zoo animals must have a dentist fill their teeth."

In order to choose the correct verb you should pay attention to "have" in the sentence.Have is a causative verb.
The following is a mini-tutorial on the use of the causative verb "have":

Form:[have + person + verb]

USE:This construction means "to give someone the responsibility to do something."

Examples:

Dr. Smith had his nurse take the patient's temperature.

Please have your secretary fax me the information.

I had the mechanic check the brakes.

Now back to your question:

have+a dentist(person)+fill(verb)

According to this #1=fill is correct.

Additional information:Sometimes "get someone to do something" is interchangeable with "have someone do something," but these expressions do not mean exactly the same thing.

Examples:

I got the mechanic to check my brakes.

(At first the mechanic didn't think it was necessary, but I convinced him to check the brakes.)

I had the mechanic check my brakes.

(I asked the mechanic to check the brakes.)

Comment: [have+person+verb]

Comment: [get+person+to+verb]

Comment: Wrong question?

Comment: @NathanTuggy .Why do you think  so?

Comment: Because you don't mention "fill" at all, only "have", and the applicability of this answer to the question is extremely hard to spot.

Comment: Varen wants us to choose the correct form of the verb and the correct form is "fill".